# Codeigniter: Populate multiple checkbox and label using array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, checkbox

In Codeigniter I am trying to populate 4 checkboxes for site options in this way

```
<label for="noindex"><input type="checkbox" id="noindex" value="noindex"  class="" />No Index</label>
<label for="nofollow"><input type="checkbox" id="nofollow" value="nofollow"  class="" />No Follow</label>
.....and so on
```

I want to use array to populate instead of writing code for each. Here I am trying using array

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?= form_label('Search Engine', 'check', array('class' => 'col-sm-4 control-label')); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-6">              
    <?php
    $checkboxes = array('noindex', 'nofollow', 'noarchive', 'nosnippet');
    foreach($checkboxes as $check):
        $data = array(
        'name' => $check,
        'id' => $check,
        'value' => $check,
        'class' => '',                      
        );

        $labels_text = array('No Index', 'No Follow', 'No Archive', 'No Snippet');
        //print_r($check);
        echo '<div class="checkbox">';
        foreach ($labels_text as $label_text):
        echo form_label(form_checkbox($data) . $label_text, $check.'-label', array('for' => $check));
        endforeach;
        //echo form_checkbox($data);
        echo '</div>';
    endforeach;
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I stuck with the labels. Where I want to display different label (of course) for each checkbox.

Can anyone help me to get different label for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$checkboxes = array('noindex'=>'No Index', 'nofollow'=>'No Follow','noarchive'=>'No Archive', 'nosnippet'=>'No Snippet');

foreach($checkboxes as $check=>$label_text):
  $data = array(
        'name' => $check,
        'id' => $check,
        'value' => $check,
        'class' => '',                      
        );   

        echo '<div class="checkbox">';

        echo form_label(form_checkbox($data) . $label_text, $check.'-label', array('for' => $check));

        echo '</div>';
    endforeach;
```

Comment: Wonderful! seems fine but little issue (may be due to the way codeigniter label function works). It is wrapping label text with `"` double quote `"No Index"` so click has not effect.

Comment: My bad, there is no need to define attributes for label to add `for`. `$id` is for the `for` attribute. I have removed the parameter and works fine. Just wonder why it is wrapping with double quotes!?